# Xamarin mono for android read xml file

Tags: c#, android, xml, mono, xamarin

Goodday,

I use xamarin mono for android and i want to load an xml from my assets and put some values in my listview. How do i do this?

this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<personen>
 <persoon>
    <id>1</id>
    <naam>Robin van Brakel</naam>
    <email>robin-brakel@hotmail.com</email>
    <apersonen>5</apersonen>
  </persoon>
  <persoon>
    <id>2</id>
    <naam>Wout van Brakel</naam>
    <email>wvanbrakel@online.nl</email>
    <apersonen>3</apersonen>
  </persoon>
</personen>
```

And this is my code:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);


        //Een nieuwe streamreader object wordt aangemaakt met het assets bestand als argument 
        StreamReader strm = new StreamReader (Assets.Open ("xmlPersonen.xml")); 
        XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(strm); 

        //De stream wordt gelezen in een xml document, dat weer kan worden uitgelezen met LINQ 
        //Het resultaat wordt uiteindelijk in een lijst met boeken gezet. Boeken is een eigen klasse met 
        //de variabelen titel, auteur, boekId en aantal pagina’s 

        var personen = (from x in xd.Root.Descendants("persoon") 
            select new Persoon { 
                id = Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("id").Value), 
                naam = Convert.ToString(x.Element("naam").Value), 
                email = Convert.ToString(x.Element("email").Value), 
                apersonen = Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("apersonen").Value) 
            }).ToList<Persoon>(); 

        foreach (Persoon bk in personen) { 
            library.Add (new cls_Libary (bk.id, bk.naam,bk.email, bk.apersonen));
        } 
    }
```

The type or namespace 'Persoon' can not be found?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check the namespace from Persoon class and from your current class.